# How to edit this code to get the categories in achieve page?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I was building part of my category.php which will get posts from custom post type "product" and sure which will be included in the category

what happen was it get ALL the posts from the custom post type "product" even it wasn't in the category .

```
<h1><?php echo  single_cat_title( '', false ) ;  ?></h1>
<h3>products in this category</h3>
<?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'post_type'=> 'product');
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

  <div class="post-row item">
    <div class="left-meta-post">
      <div class="post-date"><span class="day"><?php the_time('d') ?></span><span class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span></div>
      <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div class="post-content">
      <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?>  <a class="rtl-read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Read More . . </a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So what are the needed edits to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

first thing that i notice, is that you use some obscure WP loop markup

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
```

Please loop with standard markup an WP_Query class

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Next thing, that is problem in your code is, that you don't even try to get posts from some category. If your taxonomy is standard category, then you will get it with standard 'cat' parameter:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4 ) );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

If it's custom taxonomy, then you need to call it with taxonomy parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: i used a lot of solution one of them was
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: and have you tried this?

maybe you have there some filters, try to add argument `'suppress_filters' => true`

Comment: it it will not help, then you must dig deeper with some https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ and find out, whats wrong with query, or try Xdebug whole WP_Query()